# Vue 3: Edit modal data flow

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue and I created a list of items and each item has an edit-button. When I click the button, I open a modal window and pass the item's reactive data object to the modal (:data="itemData") to fill a form for editing the data.

When editing the data in the form, I don't want the original items in the list to change. Therefor I made a copy of the data prop (not sure if I did this correctly). It seems to work. When I save the changes, the list updates accordingly.

The problem is, this only works once. After editing and saving e.g. the 1st item in the list and then try to edit the 2nd item, nothing happens. I expected the edit form to update and show the 2nd item's data. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is and how to  do this properly. Please help.

Here's a very basic dummy for demonstration:

**App.vue:**

```
<script setup>
  import { reactive } from 'vue';
  import EditModal from './components/EditModal.vue'
  import ListItem from './components/ListItem.vue'

  const state = reactive({
    items: [
      { id: 1, title: 'Item 1' },
      { id: 2, title: 'Item 2' }
    ],
    currentItem: null,
    showModal: false
  });

  function editItem(itemData) {
    state.showModal = true;
    state.currentItem = itemData;
  }

  function updateItem(itemData) {
    state.items = state.items.map(item => item.id === itemData.id ? itemData : item);
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <EditModal
      v-if="state.currentItem"
      :show="state.showModal"
      :data="state.currentItem"
      @save="itemData => updateItem(itemData)"
    />

    <ListItem
      v-for="itemData in state.items"
      :data="itemData"
      @edit="itemData => editItem(itemData)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**ListItem.vue:**

```
<script setup>
  defineProps(['data']);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ data.title }}
    <button @click="$emit('edit', data)">Edit</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**EditModal.vue:**

```
<script setup>
  import { reactive, toRaw } from 'vue';

  const props = defineProps(['show', 'data']);
  const data = Object.assign({}, toRaw(props.data));
</script>

<template>
  <div v-show="show">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-inner">
        <input v-model="data.title">
        <button @click="$emit('save', data)">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Without the following line I can edit item 1 and then item 2, but while editing the list changes as well:

const data = Object.assign({}, toRaw(props.data));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better solution (my opinion)

There is a getter and setter in 'computed' you could try to use it instead of using 'watch'
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed

```
<script setup>
  import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';

  const props = defineProps(['show', 'data']);
  const state = reactive({ data: null });

  const inputData = computed({
    get() { return props.data; },
    set(newVal) { state.data = newVal },
  });
</script>

<template>
  <div v-show="show">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-inner">
        <input v-model="inputData">
        <button @click="$emit('save', state.data)">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I solved it. If someone has a better solution, please let me know.

**EditModal:**

```
<script setup>
  import { toRaw, reactive, watch } from 'vue';

  const props = defineProps(['show', 'data']);
  let data = Object.assign({}, toRaw(props.data));
  let state = reactive({ data: data });

  watch(() => props.data, (selection, prevSelection) => {
    data = Object.assign({}, toRaw(selection));
    state.data = data;
  });
</script>

<template>
  <div v-show="show">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-inner">
        <input v-model="state.data.title">
        <button @click="$emit('save', state.data)">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```